# Reverse loop for palindrome

Tags: python-3.x, loops, reverse

My teacher wants me to use a reverse loop instead of the reverse function I am using right now. I can't seem to get one that works.

```
def palindrome():
    myInput = input("Enter a Word: ")
    word = myInput[::-1]
    if myInput == word:
        print("That is a palindrome")
        return True
    else:
        print("That is not a palindrome")
        return False
palindrome()
```

Comment: This is working fine for me.

Comment: http://imgur.com/qzqVE0G

Comment: Yeah I know it works its just my teacher wants me to use a loop instead of that reverse function.

Comment: Its reverse loop implementation.  list(reversed(myInput)) == list(myInput) would have used reserved function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def palindrome():
    string = input("Enter a Word: ")
    for i,char in enumerate(string):
        if char != string[-i-1]:
            return False
    return True
```

Edited for below comment:

> the enumerate() function adds a counter to an iterable.

```
>>> string = "PARAM"
>>> for count, elem in enumerate(string):
...     print count, elem
... 
0 P 
1 A
2 R
3 A
4 M
```

> so line `if char != string[-i-1]` will try to match one character from front and one character from end.

Comment: Can you explain how and why this works? I'm pretty new to the language

Comment: Cheers.If my answer solved your problem, flag it as accepted as it may help other users also.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the code below, but I really recommend you to try it yourself first. (Because, if you're able to write a recursive call, you should be able to write an iterative one yourself too.)

```
def reverse(text):
      rev = ""
      final = ""
      for a in range(0,len(text)):
            rev = text[len(text)-a-1]
            final = final + rev
return final
```